# Rails 2.3: how to handle complex joins without writing custom SQL code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I've looked trough the already asked questions but couldn't find an answer.

I've some models:

Each User can cast many Votes, each Vote is linked to one Post, each Post can be linked to many Users.  Each User can cast only one vote per post.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :through => :user_posts
  has_many :user_posts
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post 
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :user_posts
  has_many :user_posts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :votes, :dependent => :destroy
end

class UserPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post  
end
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to count how many times "User A" has voted for posts that belongs to "User B" in the last day.

I can do this with a full SQL query but I'd like to know if there is an easied "Rails-friendly way" to perform this.

Thanks!

Augusto

Comment: What is the UserPost model? Why do you have it? How do you determine if a Post belongs to a user?

Comment: UserPost model is:  

class UserPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post  
end

Comment: So a Post can belong to many users. Is that correct?

Comment: @Pan: right!  @post.users outputs the array of its users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
user_a.votes.count(:conditions => { :post => { :users => user_b }, :date => Date.today }, :joins => { :post => :users })
```

Comment: By the way do you know some resource online where I can find some good documentation on how to build join queries in Rails?